# building libgit2 using libssh - editing calling convention?

Tags: git, ssh, libgit2, libssh2

I am trying to build libgit2 to include ssh and I am following the tutorial found here [Adding ssh support to the Visual Studio 2015 Git plug-in](http://randomswdev.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/adding-ssh-support-to-visual-studio.html)

In the comments section Tom Sollas mentions doing the following after running cmake on the libssh

> - open the resulting build\libssh2.sln in VS2015, edit the libssh2 project and set the calling convention to __stdcall (/Gz), set the build type to "Release" and rebuild all (Note: Must be Release!)

I haven't a clue what is meant by "editing the project and setting the calling convention." I imagine this is a C++ thing? which I have never used. I'm a c# developer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a C/C++ thing.  [Calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) specify how functions take arguments off the stack and return results;  The caller needs to provide arguments in the way that the called function expects to receive them, or else the program will crash.

Open the Properties page for the project.  In the Compiler section, you'll find Calling Conventions.  By default, they will be `cdecl`.  Change them to `stdcall`, then build the project.